# convert .dat into .csv in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to convert a data set of an `.dat` file into `csv` file. The data format looks like,

`Each row begins with the sentiment score followed by the text associated with that rating.`

[image: Image of the .dat file]

I want the have sentiment value of (-1 or 1) to have a column and the text of review corresponding to the sentiment value to have an review to have an column.

WHAT I TRIED SO FAR

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np  
import csv

# read flash.dat to a list of lists
datContent = [i.strip().split() for i in open("train.dat").readlines()]

# write it as a new CSV file
with open("train.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(datContent)
def your_func(row):
    return row['Sentiments'] / row['Review']

columns_to_keep = ['Sentiments', 'Review']
dataframe = pd.read_csv("train.csv", usecols=columns_to_keep)
dataframe['new_column'] = dataframe.apply(your_func, axis=1)

print dataframe
```

Sample screen shot of the resulting train.csv it has an comma after every word in the review.

[image: Output of the train.csv]

Comment: So what did you learn about pandas' ```read_csv```, it's a one-liner.

Comment: What is separating the score from the text? A space or a tab?

Comment: @sascha that keeps giving error prolly due to the fact its not .csv format. I did df = pd.read_csv("train.dat")

Comment: ```read_csv``` has parameters and csv is a very general format! But Evan is right; it might be easier if it's a tab; if it's a space; you can do it too; but it will be harder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all your rows follow that consistent format, you can use `pd.read_fwf`. This is a little safer than using `read_csv`, in the event that your second column also contains the delimiter you are attempting to split on.

```
df = pd.read_fwf('data.txt', header=None, 
        widths=[2, int(1e5)], names=['label', 'text'])

print(df)
   label                       text
0     -1  ieafxf  rjzy xfxk ymi wuy
1      1     lqqm  ceegjnbjpxnidygr
2     -1  zss awoj anxb rfw  kgbvnl
```

`data.txt`

```
-1  ieafxf  rjzy xfxk ymi wuy
+1  lqqm  ceegjnbjpxnidygr
-1  zss awoj anxb rfw  kgbvnl
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED hey the problem lies in the fact I have no headers as in label and text, do I just make them up?

Comment: @KoushikProgrammer I know you don't have them, I made them up for you. You don't have to modify your data file.

Comment: @COLDSPEED thanks. Hey what is the purpose of int(1e15)?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, read_csv would be appropriate here.

```
df = pd.read_csv('train_csv.csv', sep='\t', names=['Sentiments', 'Review'])

  Sentiments     Review
0         -1    alskjdf
1          1      asdfa
2          1       afsd
3         -1        sdf
```